# Don't understand why I'm getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent

I don't understand why I my app keeps on crashing. According to LogCat, it is caused by a NullPointerExeption on a line, however, I cannot find why it is occurring. What's supposed to happen is an image resource for an ImageView is changed in MainActivity by pressing a button on another activity. I have followed multiple guides, but get the recurring error. From what I can see it occurs when extra information is passed through an Intent, something is null but I cannot find it.

**LogCat**

```
05-03 22:33:03.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31629): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 22:33:03.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31629): at com.crackedporcelain.crackedcalibration.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
```

**Line 21 (offender in MainActivity)**

```
String gridPressed = content.getString("gridPressed");
```

**Main Activity (receiver)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bundle content = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Set image based on which button was pressed
    String gridPressed = content.getString("gridPressed");
    ImageView spotlightOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.variousOne);

    if (gridPressed.equals("one")) {
        spotlightOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    } else if (gridPressed.equals("two")) {
        spotlightOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    } else {
        spotlightOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    }

    ImageView buttonGrid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phoneReference);

    buttonGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    "com.crackedporcelain.crackedcalibration.IDENTIFICATION"));
        }
    });
}
```

**Other Activity (sender)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.identification);

    ImageView gridButton1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonImage1);
    ImageView gridButton2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonImage2);

    gridButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    gridButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonImage1:
        Intent oneA = new Intent(IdentificationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        oneA.putExtra("gridPressed", "one");
        startActivity(oneA);
        break;
    case R.id.buttonImage2:
        Intent oneB = new Intent(IdentificationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        oneB.putExtra("gridPressed", "two");
        startActivity(oneB);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Additional Info**

Layouts for these classes are setup correctly, they work fine. It only force closes when I try to use Intents.
All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where is line 21 in MainActivity?

Comment: if NPE gets thrown at this line: `String gridPressed = content.getString("gridPressed");` then `content == null`

Comment: Line was actually mentioned in question @cybersam

Comment: @donfuxx because getString() can't possibly be wrong? I don't even see what type `content` is.

Comment: because NPE gets thrown if you call a method on an object that points to null and the only method called in line 21 is getString. So the Bundle "content" is null. @fstd

Comment: @donfuxx my point was, the exception could have as well originated inside getString(), then (naturally) propagated up the call stack.  However, long time no java, I might as well be wrong.

Comment: if would be like you said then in the exception stacktrace another line would be mentioned ;-) @fstd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The received intent did not contain any extra values. Make sure the code sending the intent had added to the intent an extra String value with the name "gridPressed". You can use [Intent.putExtra(String, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for this purpose.

`Intent.getExtras()` will return `null` if there are no extra values. In addition, [Bundle.getString(String key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will return `null` if the `Bundle` does not contain the key.

Finally, be sure to check that MainActivity is not invocable in any other way (like when the app icon is clicked). If that is possible, then this version of `onCreate()` will work better:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView spotlightOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.variousOne);

    // Set image based on which button was pressed, if any
    String gridPressed = getIntent().getStringExtra("gridPressed");
    if ("one".equals(gridPressed)) {
        spotlightOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    } else if ("two".equals(gridPressed)) {
        spotlightOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    } else {
        spotlightOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    }

    ImageView buttonGrid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phoneReference);

    buttonGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    "com.crackedporcelain.crackedcalibration.IDENTIFICATION"));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't: `oneA.putExtra("gridPressed", "one");` or `oneB.putExtra("gridPressed", "two")` already do this? @cybersam

Comment: Have you indicated all the ways that MainActivity can be invoked? For example, is MainActivity invoked when your app is launched using the app icon? If so, the extra values will not be provided.

Comment: It is invoked when the app is launched... Is there any way by this? @cybersam

Comment: Sure, check for `null` before using content. If it is null, you can act appropriately for a new startup (and avoid using the non-existent extra data), otherwise act appropriately for a click.

Comment: @Rossw19 See my updated answer for a better implementation of `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're getting a NPE because you are not sending a bundle from the sender activity rather just a string extra. So, to access the String extra in the receiver activity, use :

   ```
   getIntent().getStringExtra("gridPressed");
   ```
2. To send bundles, you need to first create a bundle, then add extras to that bundle and then pass the bundle with the intent :

   ```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("KEY", "VALUE");
   intent.putExtras(bundle);
   ```

If you send a bundle as mentioned in 2, your existing code in the receiving activity will work, otherwise you can change the code in the receiving activity as mentioned in 1.